# Show WooCommerce variation dropdown as a modal box

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, modal-dialog

I'm looking for a way to change the product variation dropdown to a modal box.

Say my product has 50 colors (50 color variations) but I don't want to show them all on a single product page. Instead, I want to show a select button and when I click on the button the modal window opens all available colors.

I would be thankful for your help.

The best option for me would be, if I can put the code into my `functions.php`.

I am using `WooCommerce Variation Swatches` plugin for displaying colors/images to product variations.

Expected result:

[image]

I have tried to add this code to functions.php to create button which triggers the modal window. The result is that it does not work as a modal, instead, the modal shows under the button. 
Also, it shows only the terms of color attributes without the option to select any color. Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'color_modal', 5 );
function color_modal() {
  $product = wc_get_product();
  echo '<button id="myBtn">Vyberte si farbu</button><div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>' . $product->get_attribute( 'pa_odtien' ) . '</div>';
    ?>
        <script>
        var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
        var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
        btn.onclick = function() {
          modal.style.display = "block";
        }
        span.onclick = function() {
          modal.style.display = "none";
        }
        window.onclick = function(event) {
          if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
          }
        }
        </script>
    <?php
    }
```

Comment: Maybe @LoicTheAztec you could help, I am your big fan :)

Comment: you can add a button in your product.php file and target that button to show and hide the color/images section. to make the section appear as popup you have write some css.

Comment: This is a bit more than just PHP. This requires CSS, JavaScript and PHP. So when I estimate this, I'll come to about 1 - 2 hours of work and testing. And you want that we do this for you, right? If yes, can you please show me, what you've already tried?

Comment: Nice thanks, but I remember you that StackOverflow is not a free coding service and you should better hire a developer.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec thank you for your answer. I certainly don't want from anyone to "work for free" for me and code something for hours. I was just expecting some suggestions from someone that has already worked on something similar.
I have added my code and if you have any ideas on how to help me to improve it I will be happy for your effort.